# Is it possible to automate Sharepoint usage reports?

Tags: excel, sharepoint, vbscript, automation, vba

I need to generate reports of sites every week. These reports include page hits, views etc. Currently i need to go to site settings->Audit reports and then select the period and generate them and paste them in excel. Is there a way to automate this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  For on premise SharePoint, the place in the API that you should be looking is the Microsoft.SharePoint.SPAuditQuery class.  This is where you can specify your criteria for what alerts you want and then use it to query the list of audit items to get all the data that you need.  Here is the SPAuditQuery class:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spauditquery.aspx
and an overall look at the process:
http://spuser.blogspot.com/2011/10/spaudit-how-to-read-from-audit-log.html